# pyspark-hbase: Failed to find data source: org.apache.phoenix.spark

Tags: pyspark, hbase, apache-phoenix

when i use pyspark read from hbase ,i wanna get info by phoenix
this is my codes:

```
df = spark.read \
   .format("org.apache.phoenix.spark") \
  .option("table", table) \
  .option("zkUrl", phoenixurl) \
  .load()
```

but there are some errors

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o137.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.apache.phoenix.spark. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:657)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

it bother me
how to fix it ,
thanks very mush

Comment: Could you show your dependencies file? So we can see, how are you adding it to build?

Comment: i have put the relative jars into the directory of the pyspark jar and i also have tried run it pointing the relative jars directory ,it did'tword